# jquery ui sortable, scroll not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have an html table. users sort the row by drag and drop. On sort the scroll is not working.

```
$("#commands tbody").sortable({
    scroll: true,
    helper: fixHelperModified,
    stop: updateIndex
});
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is add `overflow: auto;` to the parent (ul, #element, whatever_you_call_it), and it should work. This ensures that even if the document changes height slightly, that when resizing, the overflow auto will retain the element's height.